# Ansible fails when running SQL Server powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ansible

I'm trying to run a SQL Server deployment PowerShell script via Ansible, but the SQL Server deployment log states the following error:

> There was an error generating the XML document.

I can log on to the windows server and run manually and there's no issue with the installation but it fails when run via Ansible.

I suspect there is some privilege escalation required and I have used become_user but this did not make a difference. Setting become doesn't work with Windows, I get

> The PowerShell shell family is incompatible with the sudo become plugin

Also so I'm a little stumped.

I'm managing both windows and linux servers and Ansible is being ran via a gitlab pipeline within a docker container

The script generates an ini file for the deployment:

Tasks:

```
---

- name: Download SQL media directory
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: "{{ package_registry }}/{{ package_name }}/{{ artifact_version }}/{{ sql_media_artifact_name }}"
    dest: C:\Temp
    force: no
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "{{ gitlab_pac }}"

- name: Extract sqlmedia zip package
  community.windows.win_unzip:
    src: C:\Temp\{{ sql_media_artifact_name }}
    dest: C:\
    creates: C:\SQLMedia

- name: Download the SQL ISO package
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: "{{ package_registry }}/{{ package_name }}/{{ artifact_version }}/{{ sqliso_artifact_name }}"
    dest: C:\SQLMedia
    force: no
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "{{ gitlab_pac }}"

- name: Download the cumulative update package
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: "{{ package_registry }}/{{ package_name }}/{{ artifact_version }}/{{ sqlcu_artifact_name }}"
    dest: C:\SQLMedia
    force: no
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "{{ gitlab_pac }}"

- name: Extract cumulative update zip package
  community.windows.win_unzip:
    src: C:\SQLMedia\{{ sqlcu_artifact_name }}
    dest: C:\SQLMedia\Updates\2017
    creates: C:\SQLMedia\Updates\2017\{{ sqlcu_artifact_name }}

- name: Download the SSMS package
  ansible.windows.win_get_url:
    url: "{{ package_registry }}/{{ package_name }}/{{ artifact_version }}/{{ ssms_artifact_name }}"
    dest: C:\SQLMedia\Updates\SSMS
    force: no
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "{{ gitlab_pac }}"

- name: Mount the ISO
  community.windows.win_disk_image:
    image_path: C:\SQLMedia\{{ sqliso_artifact_name }}
    state: present

- name: Create the conf file
  ansible.windows.win_template:
    src: ConfInput.txt.j2
    dest: C:\SQLMedia\SQLServerSilentInstall\Conf\ConfInput.txt

- name: Run the deployment install script
  ansible.windows.win_shell: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\MSSQL-SilentInstall.ps1 -Install
  become_user: Administrator
  args:
    chdir: C:\SQLMedia\SQLServerSilentInstall
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: app_db
  gather_facts: yes
  become: no
  roles:
    - roles/app_db
    - roles/win_locale
```

Ansible error:

```
TASK [app_db : Run the deployment install script] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host-name]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\\MSSQL-SilentInstall.ps1 -Install", "delta": "0:00:23.091338", "end": "2021-06-01 03:51:50.476653", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-06-01 03:51:27.385314", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: `The PowerShell shell family is incompatible with the sudo become plugin` => Have you tried setting `become_method: runas` ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-and-windows

Comment: @Zeitounator Thank you. That solved it.